# A way to transform by special epsg-code

Tags: qgis, epsg

In my country, we have a special epsg-code for transformation (#4649). In the definition (http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:coordinateOperation:EPSG::4649&reportDetail=short&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=), a `shTransCom.dll` will be listed as a component. I have this.

Now my problem - there are several shapefiles I want to transform by using epsg:4649. One idea is to use QGIS- but how to integrate the dll-file? Normal epsg-code in my knowledge are ony a long list of parameters.

On the other side, my idea is to extract the coordinate - transform in another step - and reinject the new coordinates. One possible packet for perl could be http://search.cpan.org/~jasonk/Geo-ShapeFile-2.51/ShapeFile.pm.

Does anyone have another or a better idea - or could describe how to integrate epsg:4649 into QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, QGIS can not handle the .dll file mentioned by EPSG.

Transformations are usually done by 3- or 7-paramaters Helmert transformation (which might be inaccurate for you) or a ntv2 grid (only with custom CRS).

The ntv2 grid is defined by EPSG::15948 and is available from http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/descrtrans/BeTA/BETA2007.gsb

Please note that EPSG coordinate transformation codes (like your 4649) are different from EPSG projection codes (like 4326 or 31467). QGIS only knows the latter ones.